# What to do now three.getWorldRotation has gone

Tags: three.js, aframe

In the previous version of Three.js I was using `getWorldRotation()`

```
  const sourceObject3D = sourceEntity.object3D

  // Rotation
  {
    const sourceAngle = three.Math.radToDeg(
      sourceObject3D.getWorldRotation().y
    )

    const prevAngle = three.Math.radToDeg(
      targetEntity.object3D.getWorldRotation().y
    )
```

This is now depreciated.

I've tried to replace it with `getWorldQuaternion()`

```
var quaternion = new three.Quaternion()
sourceEntity.object3D.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion )
var vector = new three.Vector3()
vector.applyQuaternion( quaternion )
const sourceAngle = three.Math.radToDeg(vector.y)

var tquaternion = new three.Quaternion()
targetEntity.object3D.getWorldQuaternion( tquaternion )
var tvector = new three.Vector3()
tvector.applyQuaternion( tquaternion )

const prevAngle = three.Math.radToDeg(tvector.y)
```

However the targetEntity Quaterion is always `Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1}`

Why would that be? And is this the right way to replace `getWorldRotation()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object3Ds rotation is represented by a `THREE.Euler` object ([source](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotation)).

Your calculations should work fine if you use it instead of the Vector3.

```
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
sourceEntity.object3D.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion )

let rotation = new THREE.Euler()
rotation.setFromQuaternion(quaternion)
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ack7ng48/2/).